# crystalreport creation using mysql database connectivity in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I need to create a crystalreport creation using mysql database connectivity in c# .Need a sample program which shows step by step procedure how to connect with mysql db.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL - this shows the detail steps. Are you stuck at a particular point?